# storyboard view trailling is not show proper

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, storyboard

I am giving constraints of stack view in this I have given leading and trailing of view 15 means equal from both end horizontal. It is showing proper Leading 15 but not showing trailing proper. 
And not showing any error.

[image: Check my constraints.]

Please check My scrollview constraints

[image: Scrollview constraints]

Also, I have checked margin too. it is not set. Can anyone help me on this issue?

Thanks

Comment: If you replace the text `NO` with `TESTING`, does it extend to the right?

Comment: yes. It extends to right but I want 'No' in a proper position means always trailling 15.

Comment: What you need to understand is that when using auto-layout / constraints, the *content* of a scroll view determines its `contentSize`... You are trying to use the scroll view's frame to determine its content's positioning. If you add a width constraint to your stack view of "equal to (scrollview-frame-width - 30)", and a leading constraint of 15, you'll get your desired results (and you won't need to add a "hidden label".

Comment: ok. Thanks for the reply. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I find the problem. It is because scrollview not getting its content width that's why it is not looking proper. So I just placed a hidden label with the same width as superview and height are 0. It gives scrollview content width and solves my problem.

[image: See the result]
I know it is the hack but it is working for me.

Anyone can correct me if any other solution exist for this problem.

Thanks

[image: See result]